# How can I exclude eia_608 subtitles when copying with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am transcoding some video files that include eia_608 subtitles (Stream #0:50(eng): Subtitle: eia_608 (c608 / 0x38303663)) which I want to exclude. Is there a way to automatically copy all the other subtitles, but exclude these?

I tried using `map -XXX` but can't figure out how to specify a type.

```
ffmpeg -i Original.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:s:eia_608 -c:a copy -c:v copy -codec copy -t 120 ffmpeg.mp4
```

This code results in the error `Invalid stream specifier: s:eia_608` as it is expecting a stream specifier and not the subtitle type.

Comment: If your transcoding, they are already excluded. If you are transmuxing you need to use a video filter to strip the SEIs

Comment: If I specify a different codec, depending on the container (m4v for example), it will fail to convert. This also happens just when remuxing. Therefore my objective was to exclude via mapping the specify subtitle file. It seems this is not possible with FFmpeg as it cannot use codec as a stream specifier, and there is no specific meta-data to filter on either (at least in this case).

Comment: There is a filter, just not the way you expect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177694/removing-eia-608-closed-captions-from-h-264-without-reencode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing EIA-608 Closed Captions from H.264 without reencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177694/removing-eia-608-closed-captions-from-h-264-without-reencode)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to map based on a codec in the current version of ffmpeg.